# Lights flickering on lamps connected to non grounded outlets?

Tags: electrical

What could cause lights to flicker plugged in non grounded outlets but the breaker not to trip? How would I proceed in troubleshooting the issue before raising the issue to electrician?

Comment: Not sure what country you are in.  But lights usually only need the neutral and hot sides of mains.  I have not seen many which also require ground.  By any chance, are these lights "high efficiency" CFLs or LEDs??  And are they plugged into a dimmer switch??

Comment: No, these are lamps plugged in wall outlet, it is 120v, I think all outlets are affected. So there is either a wire exposed or something else.

Comment: It is possible to replace wall switches with dimmer switches and control outlets using the dimmer switch.  But I will remove the answer since it does not address your question.

Comment: What kind of lamps are these? What country?